# Problema con polimorfismo y vectores en C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Hola que tal estoy haciendo un prgrama en C++ con POO y polimorfismos pero tengo un problema al utilizar vectores esto es lo que tengo de codigo:

### Clase Persona(clase padre)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Persona //clase padre
{
    private:
        string nombre;
        int edad;
    public:
        Persona();
        Persona(string, int);
        string getNombre();
        int getEdad();
        void setNombre(string);
        void setEdad(int);
        virtual void addData();
        virtual void showData();
};
Persona::Persona() {}
Persona::Persona(string _nombre, int _edad)
{
    nombre = _nombre;
    edad = _edad;
}
string Persona::getNombre()
{
    return nombre;
}
int Persona::getEdad()
{
    return edad;
}
void Persona::setNombre(string _nombre)
{
    nombre = _nombre;
}
void Persona::setEdad(int _edad)
{
    edad = _edad;
}
void Persona::addData()
{
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << " NOMBRE : ";
    getline(cin, nombre);
    cout << endl;
    setNombre(nombre);
    cout << " EDAD : ";
    cin >> edad;
    setEdad(edad);
}
void Persona::showData()
{
    cout << " NOMBRE : " << getNombre() << endl;
    cout << " EDAD : " << getEdad() << endl;
}
```

**Clase Empleado**

```
#pragma once
#include "persona.h"
class Empleado : public Persona //clase padre
{
    private:
        string cargo;
        int sueldo;
    public:
        Empleado();
        Empleado(string, int, string, int);
        string getcargo();
        int getsueldo();
        void setcargo(string);
        void setsueldo(int);
        void addData();
        void showData();
};
Empleado::Empleado(){}
Empleado::Empleado(string _cargo, int _sueldo, string nombre, int edad) : Persona(nombre, edad)
{
    cargo = _cargo;
    sueldo = _sueldo;
}

string Empleado::getcargo()
{
    return cargo;
}
int Empleado::getsueldo()
{
    return sueldo;
}
void Empleado::setcargo(string _cargo)
{
    cargo = _cargo;
}
void Empleado::setsueldo(int _sueldo)
{
    sueldo = _sueldo;
}
void Empleado::addData()
{
    string cargo;
    int sueldo;
    cin.ignore();
    Persona::addData();
    cin.ignore();
    cout << " CARGO : ";
    getline(cin, cargo);
    cout << endl;
    setcargo(cargo);
    cout << " SUELDO : ";
    cin >> sueldo;
    setsueldo(sueldo);
}
void Empleado::showData()
{
    Persona::showData();
    cout << " CARGO : " << getcargo() << endl;
    cout << " SUELDO : " << getsueldo() << endl;
}
```

**Clase Estudiante**

```
#pragma once
#include "persona.h"
class Estudiante : public Persona //clase padre
{
private:
    string carrera;
    int notaFinal;
public:
    Estudiante();
    Estudiante(string, int, string, int);
    string getcarrera();
    int getnotaFinal();
    void setcarrera(string);
    void setnotaFinal(int);
    void addData();
    void showData();
};
Estudiante::Estudiante() {}
Estudiante::Estudiante(string _carrera, int _notaFinal, string nombre, int edad) : Persona(nombre, edad)
{
    carrera = _carrera;
    notaFinal = _notaFinal;
}
string Estudiante::getcarrera()
{
    return carrera;
}
int Estudiante::getnotaFinal()
{
    return notaFinal;
}
void Estudiante::setcarrera(string _carrera)
{
    carrera = _carrera;
}
void Estudiante::setnotaFinal(int _notaFinal)
{
    notaFinal = _notaFinal;
}
void Estudiante::addData()
{
    string carrera;
    int notaFinal;
    cin.ignore();
    Persona::addData();
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;
    cout << " CARRERA : ";
    getline(cin, carrera);
    cout << endl;
    setcarrera(carrera);
    cout << " NOTA FINAL : ";
    cin >> notaFinal;
    setnotaFinal(notaFinal);
}
void Estudiante::showData()
{
    Persona::showData();
    cout << " CARRERA : " << getcarrera() << endl;
    cout << " NOTA FINAL : " << getnotaFinal() << endl;
}
```

**Clase Main**

```
#include "estudiante.h"
#include "empleado.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int menu() {
    system("cls");
    int op;
    cout << "########################" << endl;
    cout << "##      MENU      ##" << endl;
    cout << "#########################" << endl;

    cout << "1.- Ingreso de datos Estudiante" << endl;
    cout << "2.- Ingreso de datos Empleado" << endl;
    cout << "3.- Salida de datos Estudiante" << endl;
    cout << "4.- Salida de datos Empleado" << endl;
    cout << "0=- Salir" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Elija una opcion" << endl;
        op = _getch();
    } while (op != '0' && op != '1' && op != '2' && op != '3' && op != '4');
    op = op - 48;
    return op;
}
int main() 
{

    vector <Persona*> persona;
    Estudiante* objEstudiante=new Estudiante();

    Empleado objEmpleado;
    vector <Empleado> employ;

    system("color A");

    int op, flag = 1, i = 0;
    char resp;

    _getch();
    do
    {
        op = menu();
        switch (op)
        {
            case 1: system("cls");
                do
                {
                    objEstudiante->addData();
                    persona.push_back(objEstudiante);
                    cout << "Desea ingresar otro dato (S/N)" << endl;
                    cin >> resp;
                } while (resp == 's' || resp == 'S');
                _getch(); break;
            case 2: system("cls");
                do
                {
                    objEmpleado.addData();
                    employ.push_back(objEmpleado);
                    i++;
                    cout << "Desea ingresar otro dato (S/N)" << endl;
                    cin >> resp;
                } while (resp == 's' || resp == 'S');
                _getch(); break;
            case 3: system("cls");

                    for (size_t j = 0; j < persona.size(); j++) {
                        cout << " \n";
                        persona.at(j)->showData();
                        cout << "----------------------" << endl;

                _getch(); break;

            case 4: system("cls");

                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        cout << " \n";
                        cout << "----------------------" << endl;
                    _getch(); break;
        }
    }while (op);

    return 0;

}
```

El problema que tengo en este caso es en la clase Estudiante al usar vectores puedo ingresar datos pero al momento de mostrar los datos solo me muestra el mismo dato varias veces

Comment: ¿ De verdad es necesario **todo** ese código ? Un [mcve] es lo que necesitamos :-)

Comment: Puedes leer solo la parte del Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El problema que tengo en este caso es en la clase Estudiante al usar vectores puedo ingresar datos pero al momento de mostrar los datos solo me muestra el mismo dato varias veces

Algo, por otro lado, lógico y normal, ya que en la lista estás ingresando, todo el tiempo, **el mismo puntero**

```
int main() 
{
  vector <Persona*> persona;
  Estudiante* objEstudiante=new Estudiante(); // <<---
```

La línea destacada es el único sitio donde se crea una instancia de `Estudiante` ... lo único que haces posteriormente es modificar los datos almacenados en ese puntero y añadir el puntero a la lista.

Si imprimes las direcciones de memoria almacenadas en el puntero obtendrás algo así:

```
0x04f5340c
0x04f5340c
0x04f5340c
0x04f5340c
0x04f5340c
...
```

Es decir, en la lista estás almacenando el mismo dato repetidas veces.

Para que el programa funcione considera crear un elemento nuevo cada vez que lo necesites:

```
        case 1: system("cls");
            do
            {
                Estudiante* estudiante = new Estudiante;
                estudiante ->addData();
                persona.push_back(estudiante );
                cout << "Desea ingresar otro dato (S/N)" << endl;
                cin >> resp;
            } while (resp == 's' || resp == 'S');
            _getch(); break;
```

Ahora podrías alegar que no te está pasando lo mismo con la clase `Empleado` ... cuando lo cierto es que el objeto solo se está creando una vez. En este segundo caso el programa funciona porque la lista almacena los objetos **por valor** en vez de almacenar punteros. Este detalle trivial es importante porque, al añadir un elemento a esta lista, el programa tiene que **crear una copia** del objeto de tipo `Empleado`. La copia será totalmente autónoma, por lo que su estado no se verá alterado si posteriormente modificas la instancia original.

Se puede ver rápidamente con tipos nativos:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a; // Copiamos el estado de 'a' en 'b'
a = 7;     // Es obvio que este cambio no afecta a 'b'
```

Y para terminar, no olvides que la memoria que reservas luego tienes que liberarla. Eso de esperar a que el programa muera para que se liberen los recursos no es una costumbre que quieras adquirir, creeme.

Has llenado la lista `persona` de objetos almacenados en reservas dinámicas de memoria y lo suyo es liberar dichas reservas cuando ya no son necesarias:

```
  }while (op);

  for( auto elemento : persona )
    delete elemento;

  return 0;
}
```